# I was facing memory error(return np.zeros((self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order) MemoryError) when executing python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, out-of-memory

I was reading some text files and splitting all the words of that textfiles and storing in a list. Then I was doing onehot encoding. When the text files size is greater than 1MB i was facing MemoryError issue. Here is my code

```
from numpy import array
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
path="D://DATA//"
data=[]
for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r',encoding="utf8") as f:
            d1=f.read()
            data+=d1.split()
            print(data)
values = data
# integer encode
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(values)
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
print(onehot_encoded)
```

This is the error which I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/onehot.py", line 21, in <module>
    onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 516, in fit_transform
    self._categorical_features, copy=True)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\base.py", line 52, in _transform_selected
    return transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 489, in _legacy_fit_transform
    return out if self.sparse else out.toarray()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 962, in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 1187, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

I was using python 64bit...
I have searched for this kind of issues and they were told to change gcv_mode I don't know how I can use in this case. please help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this data some text data? If you do OHE on text data , you will definitely run out of Memory!

Comment: yes, it is text data. How to solve it??

Comment: The error occurs when `onehot_eoncoder` tries to return a dense array.  It generates a sparse matrix, but because you specified `sparse=False`, it has to do the `out.toarray()`, and fails because an array of `self.shape` is too large for memory

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you are playing with some text data , Doing a one hot encoding scheme on text data and you will definitely run out of memory , I would suggest you play with

Sklean's TfidfVectorizer or CountVectorizer

This : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.shape)
```

Or you Can play with **CountVectorizer**:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']
>>> print(X.toarray())  
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]
```